# How to get content from the Wikipedia API for a movie?

Tags: case-sensitive, wikipedia-api, capitalization

I tried to get the description of the movie "Your Highness" from the Wikipedia API but it gives me nothing.

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=query&titles=your%20highness&prop=revisions&rvprop=content

When I google "Your Highness" wikipedia shows up as the third result, that's the page that I want the API to give me.

Also I just want the text of the description of the movie, no wiki-syntax mixed in or anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was wrong before about the problem being a space - it looks like it was just capitalization. If we *just* change your URL to use `Your%20Highness` instead of `your%20highness` it works:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=query&titles=Your%20Highness&prop=revisions&rvprop=content

EDIT: While not all titles are title-cased (such as "The Name of the Rose") if you use the `&redirects` query parameter, it *sometimes* helps - it certainly helps in "the name of the rose" but not for "your highness" for some reason. Wouldn't like to say why, but it's probably worth more investigation...

Comment: Thanks, do I also always capitalize each word? Or is there some pages where they aren't all capitalized? If I miss one capitalization it gives me nothing.

Comment: @curtis: I believe everything is capitalized - you should probably do some tests to give you confidence though.

Comment: Wikipedia titles are case-sensitive **except** the first character, which always becomes upper-case if it is a lower-case letter.

Comment: If you always use capitals it seems to tell you when you shouldn't, which is good. I just coded it to parse out the redirect and go to that URL. http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=query&titles=Life%20Support&prop=revisions&rvprop=content

Comment: `&redirects` sometimes works and sometimes not, because it requires that someone actually created the redirect. For example, the page ["Your highness"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Your_highness) doesn't exists, but the page ["The name of the rose"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_name_of_the_rose) does exist and it's a redirect to "The Name of the Rose".